# How do I prove the value of $\lim_{x \to 3} {{x^3 - 27} \over {x - 3}}$ is 27?

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the value of $\lim_{x \to 3} {{x^3 - 27} \over {x - 3}}$ and use an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof to show your answer is correct.

This is a review problem, I always forget how to do this. All I need is to see how it's done.

Could someone show me a detailed proof please? Thank you!

Comment: You could perhaps use $\;x^3-27=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)\;$ ...

Comment: Edited the question. What I need help with is not finding the value, but proving it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, do the $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ with the reduced quadratic instead: that's the intention.

Comment: The first step to proving it is using what @Don says. Try it!

Comment: for each $x\neq 3$ this function equalizes $x^2+3x+9$ so...

Comment: @DonAntonio I don't know how to write an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof like this. I don't even know what the proof should look like. Could you show me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{x^3-27}{x-3}=\lim_{x \to 3}\frac{(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)}{x-3}=\lim_{x \to 3}x^2+3x+9$$

So Proceed by saying the usual:

$$\forall \quad \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \quad \delta>0 : |x-3|<\delta \Longrightarrow |\frac{x^3-27}{x-3}-27|<\epsilon$$

Replace the first form with

$$\forall \quad \epsilon>0 \quad \exists \quad \delta>0 : |x-3|<\delta \Longrightarrow |x^2+3x+9-27|<\epsilon$$

You can simplify the epsilon modulus with

$$|x^2+3x-18|<\epsilon$$

So you want to end up at

$$|x-3||x+6|<\epsilon$$

When this happens, it helps if you define your delta (without loss of generality). e.g. $$Let \quad \delta :=1$$
Open up this modulus involving delta:
$$if \quad |x-3| < \delta=1$$
$$\Longrightarrow -1<x-3<1$$
$$\Longrightarrow-(9+1)<9-1<x-3+9=x+6<9+1$$
Ie
$$\Longrightarrow |x+6|<10$$

so you find a condition for your $\epsilon$

So we require $$\epsilon := 10\delta $$
(since $\delta$ equaled 1 for x+3 and we ended up with 10!)

and then just work in reverse!

Comment: Can you elaborate why it is possible to define $\delta :=1$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Then,

\begin{align}
|&\dfrac{x^3-27}{x-3}-27|
\\=&|(x^2+3x+9)-27|
\\=&|x^2+3x-18|
\\=&|((x-3)+3)^2+3((x-3)+3)-18|
\\=&|(x-3)^2+5(x-3)|
\\\leq& |x-3|^2+5|x-3|
\end{align}

Can you proceed from here?